# How to capture Chef::Log.info in kitchen test

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

When I run

```
   kitchen test
```

or

```
   kitchen test --log-level info
```

No logs that I have in my recipe under test ie.

```
   Chef::Log.info("How to make appear in kitchen output?")
```

are displayed in kitchen's output to console. Anyway to make this happen?

driver: vagrant

provisioner: chef-solo

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update: Martin's answer is no longer true as of version 1.7.0 of Test Kitchen (See [pull request #950](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/pull/950)).

According to the [Dynamic Configuration doc](http://kitchen.ci/docs/getting-started/dynamic-configuration), "Since Kitchen 1.7.0 the log level for the provisioner is no longer related to the Kitchen log level."

It gives the following example of setting the `log_level` in *.kitchen.yml*:

`provisioner:
  name: chef-zero
  log_level: <%= ENV['CHEF_LOG_LEVEL'] || auto %>`

My tests confirm that:

- `Chef::Log.debug` calls *aren't* logged when simply running `kitchen converge -l debug`.
- `Chef::Log.debug` calls *are* logged after setting `log_level: debug` in *.kitchen.yml*.

Comment: Note that the log_level option is not currently documented in the [.kitchen.yml syntax doc](https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html).
See also [v1.7.0 entry in the CHANGELOG](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v170-2016-04-01)

Answer (score 1):

You [can set the verbose level](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen#usage) when running test-kitchen, e.g. `kitchen test -l debug`. What you're seeing is that by default, Chef runs at WARN and higher, so by default, INFO is hidden. This is true with `chef-client` as well. Using `-l debug` on your kitchen command will pass `-l debug` to the `chef-client` command, and then you'll see INFO-level logs too.

Comment: Hi - I've tried this but still aren't seeing any logs from the recipe - does this apply to chef-solo ? -- actually disregard - docs say it does - ill try a few different log levels and see what happens

Comment: I use this all the time, so I'm pretty sure that is correct. I only use it with `-l debug` though.